# C# deploying an app with code-first LocalDB database breaks the database connection

Tags: c#, localdb

I am having trouble.  When I run my application from inside visual studio 2022, everything is kosher.  When i attempt to deploy it, I get a stack trace error the first time i try to use it to access the database.  I do not understand this because i thought the whole purpose of code-first was it generated the database for you.
The error i get is this:

> System.ArgumentException: Expansion of |DataDirectory| failed while processing the connection string. Ensure that |DataDirectory| is set to a valid fully-qualified path.
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.ExpandDataDirectory(String path)
> at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetOrGenerateDatabaseNameAndGetFileNames(SqlConnection sqlConnection, String& databaseName, String& dataFileName, String& logFileName)
> at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
> at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)
> at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
> at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) at System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) at System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass66_0`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__0() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<>c.<InitializeDatabase>b__58_0(InternalContext c) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
> at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
> at Twinkly.DBFunctions.GetSavedStringInfo(String name)

I just used basic code-first stuff I got off of the internet.

This is all of it:

```
public class CodeFirstContext : DbContext
{
    public CodeFirstContext() : base()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<CodeFirstContext>());
    }
    public DbSet<ErrorLog> ErrorLogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SavedStringInfo> SavedStringInfos { get; set; }
}
```

When it hits the first linq query, the below error happens.
How do I make this work when I deploy?  I want to send out copies of my app for beta testing.

Comment: What does your connection string in your config file look like in the deployed environment??

Comment: I think you hit exactly on what the issue is.  I was letting code first set the connection string.  I don't know why it isn't creating a new db at deployment but i have now successfully moved the existing db to where the app wants it and it connected to it.  I'm going to have to bundle a blank db with the publish i suppose.  Not really a huge deal since it's 8MB empty.  It was attempting to connect to a folder deep into app data.